# Updating the wxBitmap on wxBitmap

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm using a single wxButton:

```
wxButtonAction::wxButtonAction(wxWindow* parent) : wxButton(parent,wxID_ANY) {
#if defined __WXMSW__
    wxIcon ms_icon(wxT("START_ICON"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO_RESOURCE, 16, 16);
    wxBitmap button_bmp;
    button_bmp.CopyFromIcon(ms_icon);
#else
    wxFileName icon_path(DATA_DIR, wxT("start.ico"));
    wxBitmap button_bmp(icon_path.GetFullPath(), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO);
#endif
    SetLabel(_("&Start"));
    SetBitmap(button_bmp);
}
```

The bitmaped button is show as expected. This method helps me change both bitmap and label when user clicks that button:

```
void wxButtonAction::updateOnAction(bool isRunning) {
#if defined __WXMSW__
    wxIcon ms_icon((isRunning) ? wxT("STOP_ICON") : wxT("START_ICON"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO_RESOURCE, 16, 16);
    wxBitmap button_bmp;
    button_bmp.CopyFromIcon(ms_icon);
#else
    wxFileName icon_path(DATA_DIR, (!isRunning) ? wxT("stop.ico") : wxT("start.ico"));
    wxBitmap button_bmp(icon_path.GetFullPath(), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO);
#endif
    SetLabel((!isRunning) ? _("&Stop") : _("&Start"));
    SetBitmap(button_bmp);
}
```

and now the resource file:

```
AAPP_ICON ICON DISCARDABLE "../data/app.ico"
ABOUT_ICON ICON "../data/about.ico"
CLOSE_ICON ICON "../data/close.ico"
START_ICON ICON "../data/start.ico"
STOP_ICON ICON "../data/stop.ico"

1 24 "../data/manifest.xml"
```

The label is changed propertly when the user toggle clicking the button, but not the icon is always in "start" bitmap. I can confirm that all icons exists in the same  folder

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `CopyFromIcon()` at all, there is an implicit conversion from `wxIcon` to `wxBitmap` under MSW (because under the other platforms they're exactly the same thing). This being said, calling it explicitly should still work, so it's not clear what the problem is.

I'd like to recommend two other things: first, prefer using PNG (with real alpha transparency) to ICO nowadays. You might find [wxBITMAP_PNG()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/group__group__funcmacro__gdi.html#ga30fc362d22b3045f58aed54fc808f203) useful to avoid the preprocessor checks, too.

Second, remove the manifest line from your `.rc` file and add `#include "wx/msw/wx.rc"` instead. This will do the right thing for the manifest and also define other stuff needed by wxWidgets applications.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the  wxBITMAP_PNG, really reduce code lines. But still don't see the icon swaping on user clicks.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code, try calling `SetBitmap()` with the stop bitmap from outside the event handler, does it work? Maybe there is something wrong with the bitmap?